# EEException: Image.visualize: Parameter 'image' is required

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

Im trying to use planet labs skysat ortho rgb high res satellite to give me an overlayed raster  but cant come up with anything: Here is my code;

parameters for Image collection

```
lc = ee.ImageCollection('SKYSAT/GEN-A/PUBLIC/ORTHO/MULTISPECTRAL')
i_date = '2014-08-03'
lc_img = lc.select(['N', 'G', 'B']).filterDate(i_date).first()
```

Initialization block

```
# Set visualization parameters for land cover.
lc_vis_params = {
    'min':200.0,
    'max':6000.0,
}

# Create a map.
lat, lon = -70.892, 41.6555
my_map = folium.Map(location=[lat, lon], zoom_start=7)

# Add the land cover to the map object.
my_map.add_ee_layer(lc_img, lc_vis_params, 'RGB')

# Add a layer control panel to the map.
my_map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())

# Display the map.
display(my_map)
```

this is the error Im getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ee/data.py in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
    329   try:
--> 330     return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
    331   except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:

6 frames
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/maps?fields=name&alt=json returned "Image.visualize: Parameter 'image' is required.". Details: "Image.visualize: Parameter 'image' is required.">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

EEException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ee/data.py in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
    330     return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
    331   except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
--> 332     raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
    333 
    334 

EEException: Image.visualize: Parameter 'image' is required.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date interval appears to be the issue, as there are no images available.

I made a few changes in order to run your code:

```
lc = ee.ImageCollection('SKYSAT/GEN-A/PUBLIC/ORTHO/MULTISPECTRAL').filterDate(i_date,i_date2)
i_date = '2014-01-01'
i_date2 = '2014-12-01'
lc_img = lc.first().select(['N', 'G', 'B'])
# Set visualization parameters for land cover.
lc_vis_params = {
    'min':200.0,
    'max':6000.0,
}

# Create a map.
lat, lon = -70.892, 41.6555
my_map = folium.Map(location=[lat, lon], zoom_start=7)
print(lc.size().getInfo()) # quantity of images for the period
# Add the land cover to the map object.
#my_map.add_ee_layer(lc_img, lc_vis_params, 'RGB') "Sorry, i don't have the add_ee_layer function :)"
mapid = lc_img.getMapId(lc_vis_params)
folium.TileLayer(
    tiles=mapid['tile_fetcher'].url_format,
    attr='False Color',
    overlay=True,
    name='False Color',
).add_to(my_map)
my_map
```

Answer (score 0):

what I did:
change the
`lc_img = lc.select(['N', 'G', 'B']).filterDate(i_date).first()` to store a variable lz like so `lz = lc.mean()` then initialize you're parameters
`lc_img = lz.select(['N', 'B', 'I'])`

```
lc_vis_params = {
    'min':200.0,
    'max':6000.0,
}

# Create a map.
lat, lon = 41.6555 ,-70.892
my_map = folium.Map(location=[lat, lon], zoom_start=7)

# Add the land cover to the map object.
my_map.add_ee_layer(lz, lc_vis_params, 'False Color')
# Add a layer control panel to the map.
my_map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
# Display the map.
display(my_map)
```

Now the raster should be visualized